# Login and Log out routing with material Sidenav

Tags: javascript, angular, url-routing, angular-routing, angular-material2

Hi I'm using `Angular 4` with `Angular Material 2` where I need some assistance in the routing. Currently I have the login component loaded when the app starts from the `router-outlet` in `AppComponent`, and when logged in the routing takes place inside the `router-outlet` in the Sidenav. The Sidenav is inside a `HomeComponent` and when logging out it cannot find the parent `LoginComponent`. How should I configure my routes, as I'm Not sure how to use child routes in Angular.

Inside app.routing

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Home.Component.html

```
<md-sidenav-container *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async as isLoggedIn">
<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" opened="true">

</md-sidenav>
<md-toolbar color="primary">
    <md-icon class="menu" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">menu</md-icon>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button md-icon-button routerLink="/dashboards/surveys">
        <md-icon class="example-icon">dashboard</md-icon>
    </button>
    <button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
        <md-icon>person</md-icon>
    </button>
    <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
        <button md-button (click)="onLogout()" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
           <md-icon>exit_to_app</md-icon>
           <span>Log out</span>
        </button>
    </md-menu>
</md-toolbar>
<div class="main-content">
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>         
</div></md-sidenav-container>
```

Any Idea of how to get the Proper routing here? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using child routes would be the best way to do it. For that you're going to need 2 router outlets in different component templates. Let's look at this example of routing:

```
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'somewhere/view',
        component: SomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'ducks',
        component: DuckComponent,
        canActivate: [QuackGuard]
      }
}
```

Then you need a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in both your `AppComponent` and `HomeComponent`

Here's the app component template with a router outlet in it:

```
<div class="content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And then, in your home component template, you'll need this:

```
<md-sidenav-container>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

(Of course, everything is cut for brevity but it's just a concept explanation anyway).

Comment: Trying to apply your fix :)